# Hide shadow under react-navigation header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I tried to hide the header shadow using the elevation 0 attribute.

On Android 10, it doesn't work. The header is gray.
In other versions, it works.

I'm using React Navigation V5.

Android 10 with elevation 0:

[image]

Android 10 without elevation 0:
[image]

Android 8.1 with elevation 0:
[image]

My code:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="DiscountsReleaseDetail"
        component={DiscountsReleaseDetail}
        options={({ navigation, route }) => {
          const { numSeq, codMaquina } = route.params.order;
          return {
            headerTitle: `Pedido ${numSeq}/${codMaquina}`,
            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
            headerBackTitleVisible: false,
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: colorCompany,
              shadowOpacity: 0, // remove shadow on iOS
              elevation: 0, // remove shadow on Android
            },
            headerLeft: () => (
              <HeaderButtonBack
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.reset({
                    index: 0,
                    routes: [{ name: 'DiscountsRelease' }],
                  });
                }}
              />
            ),
          };
        }}
      />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with lib itself, I suggest to open a new issue in the GitHub repo

Answer (score 6):

try this setting. worked for me.

```
headerStyle: {
backgroundColor: "black",
shadowOpacity: 0,
shadowOffset: {
    height: 0,
},
shadowRadius: 0,
elevation: 0}
```